# Meteor: How to return JSON from cross origin request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, meteor

I have a Meteor application I would like to let users retrieve data from via an ajax request. Currently if I send the ajax request it returns the HTML.

I understand I might have to do something with the headers but I can't quite figure out what given the flood of javascript, json, ajax search results that diminish the results of what I am looking for.

I am also curious how Meteor would even handle this since it is a one page application with dynamic headers which I am not sure I have control over.

So basically I need a client from cross origin to ping myurl.com/?myQuery=yadada and get back some data

Comment: I dealt with a similar situation before,  and the way I got around it was to make the ajax call to my own script at the server level. Which in turn would retrieve the JSON and pass it back to the front end as the result of the ajax call.

Comment: With meteor? I do not think that would work in this case with how Meteor compiles its scripts.

Comment: As CORS, the server must return with header include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. I wonder what if the server doesn't.

Comment: How do you plan to send the JSON data? You can use the `webapp` package or a higher level API-creation package, as mentioned in [the guide](https://guide.meteor.com/routing.html#server-side).

Comment: I'm exploring it. I don't plan to send it in any specific way. Just want users to send a request to a URL with query params and receive JSON.

Comment: Then take a look at the links in my comment. Once you decide to implement it, don't do it on the root URL (as in your post), but create a designated path for it (if you create them manually).

Comment: Yup that did it, your comment led me to this https://atmospherejs.com/simple/rest which solved it.